# Creating a less random list

Tags: list-manipulation, random

I'm trying to create an list like `{1,3,2,5,8,7,9}`, or `{2,1,5,6,4,7,9}`, that the elements in each list is sorted in a rough order, but not exactly sorted. The `Random` functions does not really work in this scenario. So how can I create this kind of list?
**UPDATE**
I suppose I should make it more clear. So there is a variable `p` that defines how "sorted" the list is, with p==1 being a totally sorted list and p==0 being an unsorted list, p==-1 means an inversely sorted list. So my goal was to generate lists with a p value in a range.

Comment: What is "roughly sorted"?

Comment: Perhaps, given a certain $p\in[0,1]$, we generate a list that has probability $p$ of being sorted? In that case, if you take some $p$ very close to $1$, you'll probably get a list that is almost sorted. I don't know how to generate such a list off the top of my head, but it is certainly an interesting problem!

Comment: A possible approach would be to pick a permutation belonging to the group $S_n$ where n is the size of the list and then act that permutation repeatedly on the list. The best permutation to pick is the one with maximal order. Take a look at this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function

Comment: I don't think @AccidentalFourierTransform's idea strikes at the OP's goal.  You could sort a list and then with probability $p$ flip interchange the last two entries and get "a list that has a probability $p$ of being sorted."  Not at all what is requested.

Comment: This is might be useful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129714/permutations-any-implementation-of-the-cayley-distance

Comment: Does this work? `RandomSample[Sort[{1, 3, 2, 5, 8, 7, 9}]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is based on the idea of Cayley Distance as you will find in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932991/catalan-number-and-cayley-distance-inequality-in-permutation-group and in [Permutations: any implementation of the Cayley distance?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129714/permutations-any-implementation-of-the-cayley-distance).

Borrowing the CayleyDistance function of @corey979:

```
 CayleyDistance[patt_, dis_] := PermutationOrder@FindPermutation[patt, dis];    
    rand[list_, n_] := 
 RandomChoice[#[[n]][[2]]] & @({CayleyDistance[Sort@list,First@#], #} & /@ 
    Gather[Permutations[Sort@list], CayleyDistance[Sort@list, #1] == 
   CayleyDistance[Sort@list, #2] &])
```

Note that n is the measure of deviation(Cayley Distance) from the sorted list that can go from 1 to the size of the list.

Hence:

```
rand[{1, 3, 2, 5, 8, 7, 9}, 3]
```

> {9, 5, 3, 7, 2, 1, 8}

is a random permutation that is at a Cayley Distance of 3 from the perfectly sorted list.

If you want to randomly choose n as well you can very well do:

```
rand[{1, 3, 2, 5, 8, 7, 9}, RandomInteger[{1,7}]]
```

> {8, 3, 2, 5, 7, 1, 9}

**Edit:**

Following the comment of @AccidentalFourierTransform one can say that if $p$ is the probability of the list being sorted then assuming that the picking of list follows a binomial distribution $Bin(n-1,1-p)$:

```
rand2[list_, p_] := 
 Module[{n = 
    1 + RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[Length@list - 1, 1 - p]]}, 
  RandomChoice[#[[n]][[2]]] & @({CayleyDistance[Sort@list, First@#], #} & /@ 
     Gather[Permutations[Sort@list], CayleyDistance[Sort@list, #1] == 
   CayleyDistance[Sort@list, #2] &])]
```

one can say:

```
rand2[{1, 3, 2, 5, 8, 7, 9}, 0.1]
```

> {3, 8, 5, 7, 9, 2, 1}

```
 rand2[{1, 3, 2, 5, 8, 7, 9}, 0.5]
```

> {8, 9, 2, 5, 3, 1, 7}

```
 rand2[{1, 3, 2, 5, 8, 7, 9}, 0.8]
```

> {1, 5, 3, 2, 7, 8, 9}

```
rand2[{1, 3, 2, 5, 8, 7, 9}, 1]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9}

Comment: Well with p=0.1 there's still possibility that the list is sorted :( But I think this answers most of the question

Comment: @t-smart If you want to be certain about the deviation from a perfect sort why don't use the `rand` function instead of `rand2` and put any number between  1 and  the size of the list as the second argument depending on the amount of scramble you want. Does that not work for you?

Comment: that would work fine,thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Define a function `swap` which swaps adjacent elements in a list.

```
swap[x_List, i_Integer] := ReplacePart[x, {i -> x[[i + 1]], i + 1 -> x[[i]]}]
```

Then define a function which swaps adjacent elements `k` times.

```
SomewhatSorted[x_List, k_Integer] :=
   Fold[swap[#1, #2] &, x, RandomInteger[{1, Length[x] - 1}, k]]
```

Increase `k` to create lists with more differences from the original input list `x`. For example,

```
SomewhatSorted[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}, 0]
```

> {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}

```
SomewhatSorted[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}, 3]
```

> {c, a, b, e, d, f, g, h}